# Regions not showing in block region demonstration

Tags: theming, 8

My regions are not showing anymore in my block regions demonstration. However they are showing in my block layout.

[image: My Regions]

The regions also not display on the pages. I don't know what I did wrong. I checked the .info.yml, libraries.yml and .theme but nothing helped. I cleared the cache and still it wouldn't display.

[image: Region demionstration]
What I did:

- Cleared the cache
- Checked info.yml
- Checked .theme
- Checked .libraries.yml
- Added blocks to the regions in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check in the drupal backend and with devel or kint if your regions / blocks exist.
2. Remove the blocks in the drupal backend.
3. Add the blocks again.
4. Clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks for this. I couldn't get my regions to appear until I disabled a single existing region on `/admin/structure/block`

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to troubleshoot, but I would really recommend looking at the .theme file again. It sounds like the region is not configured/configured incorrectly there. Maybe post that here?

Comment: This is my info.yml: http://pastebin.com/i8S45phD and this is my libraries.yml: http://pastebin.com/wiiPfhPM. My .theme file is currently empty and its still not working.

Comment: I'm sorry I had a blank moment. I didn't mean .theme. I meant you should check page.html.twig. This is where you define how regions are displayed and where. If you've added a new region in the info.yml but not added it there, you won't see the new region. You can find the page.html.twig under templates in your /theme directory. Let me know how that goes!

Comment: This is my page--front.html.twig http://pastebin.com/dbfYPUf4

Comment: In the info.yml you have custom regions called things like call_to_action and quotes, but nowhere in your twig file are you actually defining these regions (using page.call_to_action or page.quotes). This is why they won't  be displaying I believe. When I was defining new regions I found it helpful to base mine off the way bootstrap did it in D8. http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bootstrap/tree/templates/system/page.html.twig

Comment: Those regions get called by some of the includes. I fixed it apparently it was some weird bug. I removed the blocks and added them again. I cleared the cache after it again. Any way its fixed but it is still weird. So far I could see there was nothing wrong with my blocks display settings in drupal. Thanks anyway :)